# Scaffold template generated by simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

```
Rails 5.2.2
Ruby 2.6
```

I have the gems slim_rails, and bootstrap installed.

I added simple_form, and did:

```
rails g simple_form:install bootstrap
```

I ended up with a template (_form.html.slim) in lib/templates/slim/scaffold, with the following in it:

```
= simple_form_for(@<%= singular_table_name %>) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?

  .form-inputs
<%- attributes.each do |attribute| -%>
    = f.<%= attribute.reference? ? :association : :input %> :<%= attribute.name %>
<%- end -%>

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

Why is this is a mix of .erb and .slim, and will it work? Should I convert the .erb parts to .slim?

## EDIT

This is how I modified the template:

```
= simple_form_for(@<%= singular_table_name %>) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?

  .form-inputs
    - attributes.each do |attribute|
      = f.#{attribute.reference? ? :association : :input} :#{attribute.name}
```

.form-actions
    = f.button :submit

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I have not tried it yet. I will be doing some tests later

Comment: Seems to work. See edit for how I modified the template

Comment: Good on ya! Nothing like giving it a go to see what happens.